# Android Studio update (version 1.2.1.1) - Cannot resolve symbol 'TintCheckBox'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

yesterday I updated my Android Studio and after the update I get a error in my SettingsActivity at this lines

```
switch (name) {
            case "EditText":
                return new TintEditText(this, attrs);
            case "Spinner":
                return new TintSpinner(this, attrs);
            case "CheckBox":
                return new TintCheckBox(this, attrs);
            case "RadioButton":
                return new TintRadioButton(this, attrs);
            case "CheckedTextView":
                return new TintCheckedTextView(this, attrs);
        }
```

TintEditText, TintSpinner, TintCheckBox, TintRadioButton and TintCheckedTextView say: 'could not resolve symbol ...'

At these import statements

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintCheckBox;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintCheckedTextView;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintRadioButton;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintSpinner;
```

it says 'unused import statement' and 'cannot resolve symbol ...'

Other import statements like

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

work perfect.

My dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

In Android SDK Manager I deleted the Android Support Repository and Library and installed it again but this did not help. I also did a clean, rebuild and gradle sync but still the same.

My Android Studio version is now 1.2.1.1

Comment: These classes don't exist in appcompat v22.2

Comment: So what did you used for these classes?

Comment: Nothing, this were classes that are not used. The code was generated automatically in a settings activity a few months before. I deleted the lines with the errors and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gabriele Mariotti said these classes dont't exist in appcompat v22.2
I updated android-studio and the support library at the same time so I thought that android-studio has a bug. 
I changed my code not using these classes and it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppCompatCheckBox` instead `TintCheckBox`.